# How to send pull request from my fork to another fork?

Tags: git, github

I forked a repository `R` as `R1`. Then I make some changes to `R1`.

B forked the repository `R` as `R2`, and `R2` becomes the mainly maintained repository.

Now I want to send pull request to `R2`, how to do?

And what if I want to keep my `R1` updated with `R2`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To send pull request to `R2` you can click `Pull Request` on `R1` (your own fork) page, then `Edit` and choose `R2` repository in `base fork` section.

To pull updates from `R2` and push them to your `R1` repository you can add new remote for `R2` like that:

```
git remote add r2 git://github.com/<path-to-r2-on-github>.git
```

Then you can pull changes from `r2/master` to your local `master` like that:

```
git checkout master # checkout your local master
git pull r2 master  # pull changes from master branch of r2 remote repository
```

And then push them to your `R1` (I assume you have `R1` configured as `origin` remote):

```
git push origin master # push changes (that you previously pulled from r2) 
                       # from local master to master in R1 repository
```

Comment: In R2's page, I can only see `Pull Requests` which list the pull requests, but not send pull request. There is `pull request` in `R1`'s page, that sends pull request to `R`.

Comment: Oh, sorry. First you have to create your own fork of `R2`. Add it as new remote to your local repository and push you pull request branch into this r2 fork. Then you'll be able to send pull request from your new r2 fork to original r2 repo. I updated the answer.

Comment: Only `Your Fork` in R2's page, I find that I can choose `R2` fork to commit into. :-)

Comment: Well, that should be caused by `R1` and `R2` being forked from the same `R` repository.