# How can I submit a Pull Request into another fork?

Tags: git, github

When I clone a repository and commit some changes, it's brilliantly simple to submit a pull request to the upstream repository. However sending one to another fork of the upstream repository seems impossible.

This ASCII art will help you understand my question.

```
upstream
    |
    +------> myFork
    |          |
    +---------------> anotherFork
    |          |           |
    |          +---------->| Merge PR form myFork
    |          |           |
    v          v           v
```

Comment: I'd _guess_ add the fork as a remote, mark your branch as "tracking" the proper remote branch, and fire away (don't forget to push to gh)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whoops, new GitHub UI made me overlook this button.

[image: img]

Also: [Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8613807/how-to-send-pull-request-from-my-fork-to-another-fork)