# How to send a pull request from parent fork to child fork?

Tags: github, fork, pull-request

This question explains 
[How to send pull request from my fork to another fork?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8613807/827927)

However, it only works if both forks are children of the same parent fork.

Now, I have a parent fork, and I want to send a pull-request to a child fork (the opposite of the usual direction). The problem is, I do not see any "Pull Request" button on my fork. What can I do?

Comment: On a repo I've forked where I have sufficient access on the upstream, too, I see "New pull request" buttons in both repos and can "compare across forks" to select from and to both repo and branch.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I click the "Pull Requests" tab, click the green "New Pull Request" button, under the heading "Compare changes" I click the "compare across forks" link, and then in the "Base repository" I select the child fork?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you’re creating a Pull Request on GitHub, you can change which way it goes. Make your fork the Base Repository.